# ARC returning object from method best practice (getting memory leak warning)

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I was creating a sample project in xcode 4.2 and noticed that the new project was setup with ARC.

I have a method shown below. Previously, I would have autoreleased the cell in the method and let the caller's table view retain the cell. With ARC, autoreleasing would not be possible,

```
- (UITableViewCell*) getCellForIndex:(int)index {

    UITableViewCell *cell =         
        [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (index == 0)
        cell.textLabel.text = profileToUse.name;
    if (index == 1)
        cell.textLabel.text = profileToUse.sex;
    if (index == 2)
        cell.textLabel.text = profileToUse.city;
    return cell;
}
```

When I running the analyze tool on the code above, it says that there is a potential memory leak of the object 'cell'.

How should the above be written using ARC so that the analyze warning will go away? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method `getCellForIndex:` allocates and returns an object, in this way it is similar to a straight `alloc` (indeed your code is just an `alloc` with some initialization).

As ARC does not see the actual implementation of a method when calling it must make an assumption about ownership of the returned object, and that assumption is that ownership is *not* transferred. When compiling your implementation ARC notices that your code violates this assumption and warns you.

The assumption can be overridden by adding an explicit attribute to your method in both the `@interface` and `@implementation`:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) getCellForIndex:(int)index __attribute((ns_returns_retained))
```

ARC will now know the object ownership is transferred. Methods in the `alloc`, `new` etc. families have this attribute added automatically. As other replies suggest you might be better off renaming your method, `newCellForIndex:` might be appropriate here as `new` is used for a combination of `alloc` and `init` which is what your method does.

*BTW: Changing your second & third `if`'s to `else if`'s would make your algorithm clearer (and slightly faster, but that is not the reason to do it).*

**Question in comment:**

ARC does introduce new attributes etc. but also uses inference and defaults so that if you follow normal Cocoa conventions you shouldn't need them too often - YMMV of course... In addition to Apple's docs you can find a description [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

Comment: This example was a simplified version of a cellcreator class I have. I have to dynamically add different cell types (label+tetfield, label+label(for datepicker invocation) and do this in couple of places, hence a class to do it in one place.

Comment: Whoa!!!. That did it. Thanks. So to use ARC, one needs to learn about a whole new set of attributes and tags and be explicit in one's intent via declaration. Does this actually speed up development compared to manually managing memory?. Is there a listing of these attributes?

Comment: I commented the attribute, renamed the method 'newCellAtIndex' and even that took away the warning. So naming could fix it as well.

Answer (score 5):

Try renaming the method to -cellForIndex:, "get"-prefixed methods have different implied behavior in Cocoa.

(Also, maybe -cellAtIndex: for consistency with NSArray, etc...)

Comment: Specifically, method prefixed with "get" are expected to take a pointer argument and return a value by reference. Take NSArray's `- (void)getObjects:(id *)aBuffer range:(NSRange)aRange` for example. I'm not sure this is actually causing the warning though. At least I can't reproduce it...

Comment: Yup. ARC can only work if your methods follow the Cocoa conventions.

Comment: catfist_man. After using CRD's suggestion of the method name : 'newCellAtIndex' the warning went away. So you were right in the spirit. Just naming it 'cellAtIndex' did not make the warning go away. Thanks!!!

Comment: I've seen new and create used across Apple's frameworks, e.g. newCellForIndex when the method is in a different class from the object being returned.